# Repetitive statements in Servlets - Best practises?

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

I'm writing a Tomcat Servlet that needs to handle some heavy traffic and I've been wondering if I could make my Servlet more performant if I opened a connection (or several) and prepared my statements at init as opposed to during the GET or POST request.

My fear is that this significantly complicates things if a connection is lost, makes recovery more difficult and in the worst case scenario completely knocks a server out of action if the max connections gets exhausted.

Therefore I'm not sure if I am thinking in the right direction. Would stored procedures be the better approach in this scenario?

Comment: IMO your best bang for buck would to be use a DBCP

Comment: If you use  a connection pool and `PreparedStatement`s, that's about as good as you can do. You can't pre-allocate those `PreparedStatement`s unless you want to handle some kind of pooling mechanism -- because `PreparedStatement`s are not thread-safe (nor are any other JDBC-related classes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first step should be to figure out what you want. If you want 'faster' you need to measure what you have now so that possible improvements can be measured to see if they actually improve.

The next thing is to figure out what you want to make faster - you seem to be asking 'where might be the best improvements in speed' without showing us any code.

I suggest you spend a little time working out where your code is spending most time in order to work out what to improve. That could be as full-on as using JVisualVM (bundled with the JDK) or some logging statements.

Once you work out where the quick wins are, you can ask a more targeted question about how to make it faster. If you're *not* using a data source (connection pool) that's almost certainly going to be a slam dunk improvement - network connections are expensive and slow.